# Converting a Object's address into a char* or char array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, char, memory-address

I am creating a simulated mobile network using named pipes for information transportation between processes. I had the idea of creating a frame class to hold the data I needed and to pass the address of that frame into the pipes. The only thing I cant figure out to save my life is how to convert the address of my frame into a character pointer in order to pass it into the write() function. This is an outline of what I have so far:

```
NFrame *frame = new NFrame;
// set frame information
char *f_address = (char*)(frame);

std::cout << f_address << std::cout;
```

whenever I call cout to verify the address all I get are unreadable characters. I've messed with reinterpret_cast and I run into the same situation.

What am I missing or am I even doing this right.

Comment: Which kind of `reinterpret_cast` actually? `char*` has as special overload along `operator<<()` actually. Try `reinterpret_cast<void*>(f_address)` to see the address value.

Comment: It's actually unclear if you want to serialize the address, or the underlying data. That's a basic difference!

Comment: The more you comment your question or answers to it, the more I find it confused and unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). It is often preferable (for ease of debugging) to serialize in some textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/). You could use libraries like [JsonCPP](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) for that. See also [s11n](http://s11n.net/) which is a binary serialization framework (but I recommend JSON).

You usually should not write the raw memory bytes of some complex C++ object, because they contain data which would be unreadable by most other programs and processes (e.g. internal pointers to your process; in another process running even the same program, they are likely to be different because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

<sup>(You might write raw memory bytes if you are sure they are read by the same process; but even that could be erroneous for C++ programs)</sup>

If (e.g. for debugging purposes) you want to simply show the *address* of some heap allocated object, you might convert it to `(void*)` like:

```
std::cout << "frame@" << (void*)frame << std::endl;
```

but such addresses (often in hexa) are not very readable and of course don't tell aything about the internal state of your `frame`.

You could define (by [overloading the output `<<` operator](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/)) your own output `<<` operator like

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const NFrame&);
```

then code `std::cout << (*frame) << std::endl`

Of course, you can replace `std::cout` by some instance of [std::ofstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) to output into some file, or some instance of std::[ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to output into a string.

Comment: unfortunately I can't add libraries that are not included on my schools system, so JsonCPP is out. But I'll do some research on ostream& since I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Is there any way for me to save the void* conversion into a readable char*? This way I can pass it into a file.

Comment: You could serialize into JSON or some other (perhaps your own) textual format quite easily (even without the help of external libraries; you'll rewrite your own serialization machinery)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "readable char*" ? And I guess you are mistaken in believing it has some precise sense. You need to write code doing output (and input) in some readable format, and that is usually called serialization

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If calling `std::cout << (void*)(frame) << std::endl;` outputs for example: `0x0x0x0x0x`, how can I save that output into a a char*, or file?

Comment: You probably mean `0x1234abc8` as an example. To get that into a file, replace `std::cout` by some appropriate instance of `std::ofstream`; to get that into a string, use a `std::stringbuffer`

Answer (score 0):

An address will have a lot of unprintable characters in it. What you probably want is to convert the address into raw bytes and then convert that into a hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `cout` 'thinks' you are passing it a string which is presented as `char *`.

Try this:

`std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(f_address) << std::endl;`

Comment: What's the purpose of `<< std::cout;` in the end of the statement? I've got some doubts that this would even compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you either misunderstood my answer or the question. He wrote "whenever I call cout to **verify the address** all I get are unreadable characters". As I understand he wants to print the address of an object but instead of it he sees unreadable characters. That is because he sends to `cout` the `char*` which is treated as array of chars of a C style string. In order to see the address he just needs to cast to another pointer type, like `void*`. You can check it yourself (unreasonable down-vote BTW).

Comment: You still don't answer my question. I've been reading through here well, and I'm sure I didn't misunderstood anything.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ohhhh.... it's a typo `std::endl` of course. Probably it was me who misunderstood your question before you edited it, sorry.